# Using splitting principle to construct to Stiefel Whitney classes

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

I want to use splitting principle to construct Stiefel Whitney classes assuming we know Stiefel Whitney class for a line bundle. Splitting principle says that

**Theorem**: Suppose we have a vector bundle $\xi$ of rank $n$ over X. Then there is a space $Y$ and  a map $f: Y \to X$ such that $f^*\xi$ is a direct sum of line bundles and $f^*: H^*X \to H^*Y$ is an injection.

So now we want to define $w(\xi)$ but we can only define $w(f^*\xi)=w(L_1)...w(L_n)$. Now if we knew this was in the image of $f^*$ we could say $w(\xi)$ is the unique element which maps to this. But splitting principle does not say the map is surjective. So my question is how does one show it is in the image?

**My try**: We want to show that $w(f^*\xi) \in Im(f^*)$. But we do secretly know that the Steifel Whitney classes exist so we should be able to prove that $w(L_1) \in Im(f^*)$. That means that there is a line bundle on $X$ which pulls back to this line bundle under $f$. Here I have used that line bundles are classified by $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Now I am not able to prove this. I tried to see if this was clear from the construction of $Y$ via projectivisation but I could not prove it. Any hints or ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Typically, the splitting principle is not used to _construct_ characteristic classes but rather to prove properties of them once they have been constructed by other means.  You can probably construct them from a more refined version of the splitting principle (that gives you a specific $Y$ where you have more control over $H^*Y$), but I would be surprised if there is any easy direct way to prove what you wish to prove.

Comment: @EricWofsey The reason I think this is possible is mainly because in the proof of splitting principle we get a line bundle with a very explicit description. So I was wondering if we could get a line bundle whose pullback is that. Also one more thing I find to be encouraging is that for the universal bundle the splitting is really nice, that is given by just product of $RP^{\infty}$ $n$ times. So since the universal case is so nice I was hoping there should be an easier way.